# Como obtener data enviando mediante axios en archivo php?

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js, axios

Estoy realizando la peticion post con axios, lo que quiero es que al ingresar los datos este rediriga al archivo php y los muestre ahi, pero no me los muestra, aqui el codigo:

archivo php:

```
<?php

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

echo $user["user"]  . " " . "como estas";

?>
```

js:

```
login: function () {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('user',this.user);
        axios.post('./Views/prueba.php',data).then(function(response){
            //this.pass = response.data;
            location.href = './Views/prueba.php';
        },function(response) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    )},
```

me muestra null a la hora de redireccionar al archivo, pero si no redirecciono y muestro la respuesta por consola si me muestra el data:

```
login: function () {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('user',this.user);
        axios.post('./Views/prueba.php',data).then(function(response){
           console.log(response.data)
        },function(response) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    )},
```

quiere decir que el archivo prueba.php si recibe el dato, solo que a la hora de redirrecionar es null, como puedo hacer? gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Yo aquí veo dos problemas.

1. No estas entiendes como funcionan las peticiones
2. El enfoque le estas dando se puede resolver de otras maneras.

Así que hay dos soluciones a esta pregunta.

Solución 1 relacionada con el problema 1.

Las solicitudes http están compuestas por varios parámetros entre ellos los mas importantes son:

- dirección
- método
- headers
- parámetros

Puedes hacer solicitudes en cualquier momento. Solo debes de recordar que el cliente. es el que va a recibir una respuesta en base a la petición que haga. Cada petición es independiente.

Por tal motivo pasa lo siguiente en tu problema.

Peticion  1:

- solicitas tu pagina.

Peticion 2:

- haces tu login.

Peticion 3

- haces una redireccion.

Lo que pasa es que cuando tu servidor responde a tu login ya tienes tu respuesta y al momento de redireccionar, la estas perdiendo. La solución a esto es que debes de guardar esa respuesta en algún lado (sea del lado del cliente o del lado del servidor).

```
<?php

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

// con estas dos lineas guardas la sesion para que en posteriores 
// peticiones puedas responder apropiadamente
session_start();
$_SESSION['status'] = true;
$_session['user'] = $user['user'];

echo $user["user"]  . " " . "como estas";
?>
```

Al momento de hacer la rediccion:
Haces lo siguiente:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status'] === true){

  echo $user["user"]  . " " . "como estas";
}
else{
  echo 'Usuario no lgueado';
}

?>
```

El segundo problema es el enfoque.

Si vas hacer re direcciones hazlas desde el lado del servidor es decir. No tienes que hacer una petición ajax si al final vas a terminar haciendo una rediccion. Las peticiones ajax se inventaron para impedir esto (gasta demasiados recursos).

Tu petición tendría que ser una petición post normal. Arias exactamente lo mismo.

```
<?php

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

session_start();
$_SESSION['status'] = true;
$_session['user'] = $user['user'];

return header('Location: pagina/destino');


?>
```

Las soluciones que di son del lado del servidor. Aun que tambien las puedes aplicar del lado del cliente. Sin embargo cuando comiences hacer tu ACL veras que funciona mas del lado del servidor que del lado del cliente.

Otra recomendación. Empieza a utilizar un framework para que después no te cuente trabajo escalar tus proyectos. en lo personal uso Laravel o Sinfony.